# FireFox extension. How i can add overlay into content area of window

Tags: javascript, firefox

My Problem in a subject. For Example: how can i dev my own [Alert Pop-ups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Alerts_and_Notifications)
I think, its possible with overlays, but i dont know how.

Comment: Are you using some javascript framework like JQuery or Prototype?

Comment: im not interesting, how it animate, i want to know how or which i can use overlay.

Comment: You are asking about doing this *in a Firefox addon*, don't you? So, with *overlay* you refer to XUL overlays?

Comment: Yes, it is of overlays based on XUL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about ol'good?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert("Hello, I'm a pop-up!");
</script>
```

Eventually, you could use jQuery UI Dialog module: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

*Edit:* I think you should also say if you are interested in JavaSctipt OR XUL based solution.

**Edit 2:**

If you want to use XUL, check out this links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Overlays
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension
- http://www.gmacker.com/web/content/tutorial/firefox/firefoxtutorial.htm

I found them very useful when I was working on my own extensions.

Truly, all you need is a:

```
<box id="myBox"> content here </box>
```

plus some logic to open it.

Comment: The decision should be based on overlays with Javascript.

Comment: Oh, Thanx, mate! But how can I place the box in the browser content?

Comment: how to set the absolute position of the box on the browser window?

Comment: Thanx to all for replys ) im check that staff!=)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use a combination of javascript and CSS. The key to the pop-up will be using a z-index in the CSS that puts it in front of the rest of the page content.

The javascript would just be used to activate and deactivate this section. You could also set up some other CSS classes to darken the rest of the page content, and apply those classes in the same javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use [BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) , its light-weight and very easy to use.

Comment: Decisions based on DOM model does not fit. The question is how or what can I use the overlay to achieve this effect.